# How to retain dropdown value on form sumission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I change the dropdown the page appears to post back because of form submission. How can I retain the dropdown selected value on form submission.
I ll be adding a webgrid which will display records based on the selected year in the dropdown. So I would also like to know the best practice of implementing such scenarios.
Here is my controller class

```
 public ActionResult NewActivity()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> lstYear = new List<SelectListItem>();
        lstYear.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Select" });
        lstYear.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "2017" });
        lstYear.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2018" });
        ViewBag.SelectedItem = "Select";
        ViewBag.YearList = lstYear;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewActivity(string strYears)
    {
        return View(NewActivity);
    }
```

and this is my View

```
<h2>NewActivity</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewActivity", "Activity", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("strYears", new SelectList(ViewBag.YearList, "Value", "Text", ViewBag.SelectedItem), new { onchange = "form.submit();" })
}
```

I am new to MVC. please guide me

Comment: Use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm, and partially update the page.

Comment: thnx.. smhw i was able to fix this. Used viewbag to pass the data back to the view.

Answer (score 1):

In POST action add the value of selected item. I assume `strYears` is the value of selected item from the DropDownList.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult NewManageActivity(string strYears)
{
    ViewBag.SelectedItem = strYears;
    return View(NewManageActivity);
}
```